# Query to pick values based on latest date in each group. Default to greatest ID if same date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following data in a table.

```
ID  Name    Date        DepositAmount

1   John    2012-01-04  70790.90
2   John    2012-01-04  73450.13
3   Samuel  2010-06-17  3700.00
4   Karen   2017-06-01  2210.00
5   Karen   2013-06-12  1300.00
```

For each person, I have to pick the latest deposit amount. If both the deposits happen on the same date, then the record with the highest ID should be picked.

So, the result would look like

```
2   John    2012-01-04  73450.13
3   Samuel  2010-06-17  3700.00
4   Karen   2017-06-01  2210.00
```

Attempt:

I tried to handle this by using a cursor but the code looked too complex and unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using [**`top with ties`**](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/use-top-filter-with-ties-option) and [**`row_number()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

```
select top 1 with ties *
from t
order by row_number() over (partition by Name order by date desc, id desc)
```

---

using [**`cross apply()`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
select distinct
    x.id
  , t.Name
  , [Date] = convert(char(10),x.[Date],120)
  , x.DepositAmount
from t
  cross apply (
    select top 1 i.id, i.Date, i.DepositAmount
    from t i
    where t.Name = i.Name
    order by i.Date desc, i.id desc
    ) x
```

---

using a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) with [**`row_number()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

```
;with cte as (
  select *
      , rn = row_number() over (partition by Name order by date desc, id desc)
  from t
)
select 
    t.id
  , t.Name
  , [Date] = convert(char(10),t.[Date],120)
  , t.DepositAmount
from cte t
where rn = 1
```

---

using an `inner join` to get the `max(id)` where a greater date for the same name [**`not exists()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx)

```
select 
    t.id
  , t.Name
  , [Date] = convert(char(10),t.[Date],120)
  , t.DepositAmount
from t
  inner join (
    select
        id = max(i.id)
      , i.Name
    from t i
    where not exists (
      select 1
      from t e
      where e.Name = i.Name
        and e.Date > i.Date
        )
    group by i.Name
    ) m 
    on t.Name = m.Name
   and t.Id = m.Id
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/GNQ24777

Comment: I like this approach.  No extra/unwanted fields +1